# Pandas divide dataframe first row with second row and so on

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below

```
    aa  bb  cc
0    1   2   3
1    2   3   4
2    3   4   5
3    4   5   6
4    5   6   7
5    6   7   8
6    7   8   9
7    8   9  10
8    9  10  11
9   10  11  12
10  11  12  13
11  12  13  14
12  13  14  15
13  14  15  16
14  15  16  17
15  16  17  18
16  17  18  19
17  18  19  20
18  19  20  21
19  20  21  22
```

then i want to divide first row with second row so on, is it possible to do that in pandas?

Comment: What do you mean by *"divide first row with second row, and so on"*: divide row 1 by row 2, then row 2 by row 3, then row 3 by row 4...? (Not each row by row2, for which you can simply use `df.div(..., axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = df.div(df.shift(-1))
print (df)
          aa        bb        cc
0   0.500000  0.666667  0.750000
1   0.666667  0.750000  0.800000
2   0.750000  0.800000  0.833333
3   0.800000  0.833333  0.857143
4   0.833333  0.857143  0.875000
5   0.857143  0.875000  0.888889
6   0.875000  0.888889  0.900000
7   0.888889  0.900000  0.909091
8   0.900000  0.909091  0.916667
9   0.909091  0.916667  0.923077
10  0.916667  0.923077  0.928571
11  0.923077  0.928571  0.933333
12  0.928571  0.933333  0.937500
13  0.933333  0.937500  0.941176
14  0.937500  0.941176  0.944444
15  0.941176  0.944444  0.947368
16  0.944444  0.947368  0.950000
17  0.947368  0.950000  0.952381
18  0.950000  0.952381  0.954545
19       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Or:

```
df = df.shift().div(df)
print (df)
          aa        bb        cc
0        NaN       NaN       NaN
1   0.500000  0.666667  0.750000
2   0.666667  0.750000  0.800000
3   0.750000  0.800000  0.833333
4   0.800000  0.833333  0.857143
5   0.833333  0.857143  0.875000
6   0.857143  0.875000  0.888889
7   0.875000  0.888889  0.900000
8   0.888889  0.900000  0.909091
9   0.900000  0.909091  0.916667
10  0.909091  0.916667  0.923077
11  0.916667  0.923077  0.928571
12  0.923077  0.928571  0.933333
13  0.928571  0.933333  0.937500
14  0.933333  0.937500  0.941176
15  0.937500  0.941176  0.944444
16  0.941176  0.944444  0.947368
17  0.944444  0.947368  0.950000
18  0.947368  0.950000  0.952381
19  0.950000  0.952381  0.954545
```

Comment: Thx..how can i add 'dd' column for if aa value > 1 then 1 else 0

Comment: @reinhard - Use `df['dd'] = np.where(df['aa'] > 1, 1, 0)`

Comment: @reinhard - Or `df['dd'] = (df['aa'] > 1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Use rolling with window of size 2 and apply division

**CODE**

```
df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0]/x[1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
          aa        bb        cc
0        NaN       NaN       NaN
1   0.500000  0.666667  0.750000
2   0.666667  0.750000  0.800000
3   0.750000  0.800000  0.833333
4   0.800000  0.833333  0.857143
5   0.833333  0.857143  0.875000
6   0.857143  0.875000  0.888889
7   0.875000  0.888889  0.900000
8   0.888889  0.900000  0.909091
9   0.900000  0.909091  0.916667
10  0.909091  0.916667  0.923077
11  0.916667  0.923077  0.928571
12  0.923077  0.928571  0.933333
13  0.928571  0.933333  0.937500
14  0.933333  0.937500  0.941176
15  0.937500  0.941176  0.944444
16  0.941176  0.944444  0.947368
17  0.944444  0.947368  0.950000
18  0.947368  0.950000  0.952381
19  0.950000  0.952381  0.954545
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
df/df.shift(-1)
```